# Prove a noetherian domain satisfying a special property is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain, and assume that for all nonzero $a,b\in R$,
the greatest common divisors of $a$ and $b$ are linear combinations of $a$ and $b$. Prove that $R$ is a PID.

Firstly I find I could prove it if I have the condition that **gcd exists in the ring**but if we take the condition away I got stuck.
Could you give me a hint？

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the conditino is meant in a way that the gcd exists _and_ is a linear combination. Something that doesn't exist can't be linear combination in my understanding

Comment: Yes, it would be a routine exercise to prove that a Noetherian Bezout domain is a PID, but interpreting it as "the GCD of $a$ and $b$ if it exists, is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$" doesn't sound right.

Comment: thanks...I misunderstood it(ノ°ο°)ノ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, since $R$ is Noetherian, $I$ is generated by $(a_1,...,a_n)$ suppose that $n$ is minimal and $n>1$, let $d_1$ be the $\gcd(a_1,a_2)$, $d_1$ is a linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$ implies that $d_1\in I$, we deduce that $I=(d_1,a_3,..,a_n)$ contradiction since we have assumed that $I$ has at leat $n$ generators, so $n=1$ and $R$ is principal.